# Java - Recommended Ways for Validation of Blank Entries

Tags: java, validation

Good day!

I am new to programming esp. JAVA and I have a problem regarding a validation. I want to create a validation wherein blank entries will not be accepted. So if i call this code:

```
entry[i].setName(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name: "));
```

if the entry is blank, it will not be accepted and an error will prompt:

```
Cannot accept blank entries!
```

Of course it could easily remedied by doing this code:

```
 String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name: ");
 while (name.equals("")){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot accept blank entries!");
       name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Name: ");
 }
```

but if i want to validate 100 fields that i don't want to have a blank entries, then my code will be messy and long...

So how could I do it better? I've read about using getters and setters or the try-catch methods to do the validation but I don't know if this kind of validation is applicable. And I don't know `HOW TO DO IT`. (iam not very experienced in programming) And if it is applicable, would I be violating the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) concept if I included an JOption message dialog box on my getter and setter methods?  What codes do programmers usually do in doing blank entries validation???

Your opinion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think this article [How to Quickly Add Validation Code to Swing UIs](http://java.dzone.com/news/how-quickly-add-validation) will help you out.

Comment: what if i am not using a swing UIs?

Comment: @newbie in that case setters should take the responsibility. They should validate the data and throw appropriate exceptions (Validation Exceptions) if the data is not valid. You should then catch these Exceptions and show user appropriate messages - which can be shown as a dialog (JOptionPane) in case of Swing UI or as a JavaScript Alert or HTML Message in case of Web Application.

Comment: Anyway, thanks.. your link is cool.. :)

Comment: Definitely do not include an JOption message dialog box on your getter and setter methods.